# Axios post request not creating user on chatengine.io

Tags: reactjs, axios

Unable to create a user on chatengine.io site. The 'then' block is not running.

```js
//creatUser.js file  
const createUser = async (req, res) => {  
  const { userId, userName } = req.body;  
axios
    .post(  
      'https://api.chatengine.io/projects/people/',  
      { username: userName, secret: userId },  
      { headers: { 'Private-Key': process.env.chat_engine_private_key } },  
    )  
    .then(apiRes => {  
      res.json({  
        body: apiRes.data,  
        error: null,  
      });  
    })  
    .catch((err) => {  
      res.json({  
        body: null,  
        error: err//'There was an error creating the user',  
      });  
    });  
};
export default createUser;
```

#### Request:

[image: request JSON]

#### Request & response headers:

[image: resquest and response header]

#### Response

[image: response JSON]

Comment: updated the above code. The err shows TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Private-Key"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is provided I see a couple of things I think. First in request pic you are passing userId but documentation says secret. I cant see any Request Header for private key. If these are not the problem I would look inside the then function. It seems wrong. You are using res.json but the response is called apiRes. It would throw res.json is not a function which would be caught by catch.

```
    var result = axios.get("https://teussa.blob.core.windows.net/public/products/test.json")
      .then((apiRes) => {
        return {
          error: null,
          body: apiRes.data
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return {
          error: err, // 'Error creating user',
          body: null
        }
      });
    console.log(await result);
```

I think this would do what you want. Here I am just using a test json document with get but it is the .then and catch that needs to change. During debugging of errors just console logging error in catch should do alot to help you discover the issue.

**EDIT**: After question updates of error and comments below the problem is process.env.chat_engine_private_key
Custom enviroment variables in react needs to start with REACT_APP_ or they wont get recognized. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: please see the whole code. I've made some changes. The error is showing "ERR_INVALID_CHAR" @Bjorne

Comment: @R_C Hve you ensured that the request body is correct and header is set correctly with the right value?

Comment: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Private-Key"] showing this. @Bjorne

Comment: now it's showing TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for  header "Private-Key"  @Bjorne

Comment: @R_C Have you also changed the .env file to use REACT_APP_?

Comment: I'm using vercel and had already deployed the .env with chat_engine_private_key as custom variable name. Should I delete this variable and add REACT_APP_chat_engine_private_key as the variable name @Bjorne

Answer (score 0):

It's not running because it's catching an error. You may want to temporarily remove the catch it console.log the error for more details